# Any curve is connected

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

In a text book I am reading we define connectedness in $\mathbb{C}$ as:

> Two sets $X,Y \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ are separated if there exist two non-empty disjoint *open* sets $A$ and $B$ satisfying $X \subseteq A$ and $Y\subseteq B$. A set $W\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is connected if it is impossible to find two separated sets $A,B$ whose union is $W$.

From this the theorem I am trying to prove states:

> Theorem:
> If $W \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ that has the property that any two points $a,b\in W$ can be connected by a curve, $\gamma$ contained in $W$, then $W$ is connected.

Here is my attempt:

## Proof

Assume $W\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is separated; then there exist open sets $A,B\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ with $W\subseteq A\cup B$.

Choose points $a\in A$, and $b\in B$ and assume for a contradiction that we can connect $a$ and $b$ with some path $\gamma$.

Since $A$ is an open set a point on the border of $A$ must be contained within $B$ by the assumption that $W\subseteq A\cup B$.

Since $B$ is also an open set, by definition of openness we can for some $\epsilon > 0$ a ball contained in $B$, such that all the points in the ball are also contained in $B$. However, since the $\epsilon\text{-ball}$ is centred on the border of $A$ there must be points in the ball that are also in $A$, thus arriving at a contradiction.

Hence, we must show that there exists a point of $\gamma$ which lies on the border of the set $A$.

[image: Ignore the border]

We know that there is a part of $\gamma$ that is inside of the set $A$, and a part of $\gamma$ that is inside $A^c$ as per the choice of $a,b$. So, we will show that there is a point on the border of $A$ by reducing the problem to a simpler problem using the real numbers. Let $L$ be the arc-length of $\gamma$ as it travels from $a$ to $b$.

Starting from the point $\gamma(t_0) = a$, we will define the set $\alpha$ to be the set which contains the positive real numbers less than $L$, corresponding to the arc-length of the curve $\gamma$ which lies within $A$ (note this set is open). Similarly, we define the set $\beta$ to be the set containing the positive real numbers less than $L$ corresponding to the arc-length of the curve $\gamma$ which lies in $A^c$ (note this set is closed).

We know that given any $0 \leq t \leq L$ we know $t\in \alpha$ or $t\in \beta$. In essence this creates a new path through the reals, and since the real numbers are dense we may conclude that there must be a point which lies on the border of $\beta$.

The fact that a point lies on the border of $\beta$ implies that there must also be a point on the border of $A$, and thus the necessary contradiction has been met. $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\blacksquare$

Is this proof valid? It feels kind of hand wavy here in the last part; do I need more justification as to why the one-dimensional problem is sufficient to solve the problem in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Try using this:  the image of a connected space (like a closed interval, the domain of your path) must be connected.  This should reduce the proof to about 2 sentences.

Answer (score 0):

First show that I = [0,1] is connected.
If p:I -> W is a curve from a = p(0) to x = p(1), then p is continuous,
whence p(I) subset W is a connected set connecting a and x.
W is the union of all curves within W, from a to a point x in W.
The curves all meet at a.
Now apply the theorem that the union of a collection of connected
sets with a not empty intersection, is connected.